# How to fix 'Notice: Undefined index:' in PHP form action

Tags: php, forms, post

I received the following error message when I tried to submit the content to my form. How may I fix it?

> Notice: Undefined index: filename in D:\wamp\www\update.php on line 4

Example Update.php code:

```
<?php

    $index = 1;
    $filename = $_POST['filename'];

    echo $filename;
?>
```

And $_POST['filename'] comes from another page:

```
<?php
    $db = substr($string[0],14) . "_" . substr($string[1],14) . "_db.txt";
?>

<input type="hidden" name="filename" value="<?php echo $db; ?>">
```

Comment: **D:\wamp\www\update.php**, Are you accessing page this way or it just a path to the file? Have you tried it on localhost?

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: filename in D:\wamp\www\update.php on line 4`, obviously he's accessing it through localhost or he wouldn't get that error.

Comment: have u added method="post" in form?

Comment: We can't help you anymore OP, we will get no where just guessing. Please post the entire code.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`Assuming` you only copy/pasted the relevant code and your form includes `<form method="POST">`

---

```
if(isset($_POST['filename'])){
    $filename = $_POST['filename'];
}
if(isset($filename)){ 
    echo $filename;
}
```

If `_POST` is not set the `filename` variable won't be either in the above example.

An alternative way:

```
$filename = false;
if(isset($_POST['filename'])){
    $filename = $_POST['filename'];
 } 
    echo $filename; //guarenteed to be set so isset not needed
```

In this example filename is set regardless of the situation with `_POST`. This should demonstrate the use of `isset` nicely.

More information here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: It depends at what stage of the script he wants to echo it, he can do that also if he wishes.. but then why assign it to `$filename` at all :P It was really just to demonstrate the use of `isset`

Comment: I personally would just do `echo $_POST['filename'];`

Comment: You're missing the point though. It doesn't matter where you use isset(), it can always be the same as isset(GET FILENAME) and isset(filename)

Comment: Its a shame i expected his form to be complete not as it was shown, thought he was just showing a snippet ! Good spot with that!

Comment: Why is this the best answer? It's wrong in almost every aspect.

Comment: I've edited it clarify my answer under the assumption of the asker to avoid confusing future visitors.

Comment: oh i didnt even  notice i put GET. I was wondering why you mentioned GET FILENAME

Answer (score 7):

```
if(isset($_POST['form_field_name'])) {
    $variable_name = $_POST['form_field_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Change $_POST to $_FILES and make sure your enctype is "multipart/form-data"

Is your input field actually in a form?

```
<form method="POST" action="update.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="test" />
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, it's enclosed within the form field. I didn't include above, that's all.

Comment: @TingPing I dont find any other issues with your code. Is that your complete code

Comment: That's a very key thing to include in your post, Ting. What happens when you var_dump($_POST) ?

Comment: var_export($_REQUEST) with var_dump($_POST) could be checked.

Comment: var_export isn't really needed, var_dump would suffice. var_export just prints out valid PHP code.

Comment: Adding the enctype did it for me

Answer (score 2):

short way, you can use Ternary Operators

```
$filename = !empty($_POST['filename'])?$_POST['filename']:'-';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!empty($_POST['filename'])){
$filename = $_POST['filename'];

echo $filename;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

`error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`

in php.ini

Comment: that would have been a comment

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
if(isset($_POST['filename'])){
 $filename = $_POST['filename'];
 echo $filename;
}
else{
 echo "POST filename is not assigned";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `isset` for this purpose

```
<?php

 $index = 1;
 if(isset($_POST['filename'])) {
     $filename = $_POST['filename'];
     echo $filename;
 }
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Use `empty()` to check if it is available. Try with -

will generate the error if host is not present
 here

```
if(!empty($_GET["host"]))
if($_GET["host"]!="")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Check your enctype in the form before submitting