# Php gives undefined index error while file upload

Tags: php, file, upload

I searched internet and I could not find a solution for the problem. I have a form and when I submit only text fields there is no problem. But when I add file input and submit the form I get undefined index error.

HTML CODE

```
    <form method="post" action="add.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10485760">
        <input type="text" name="topic" style="width:300px;" value="cars" />        
        <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add"/>
    </form>
```

PHP CODE

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    // Form
}
else echo'NOOO';
```

This code always give NOOO when uploading file. I have controlled php.ini and upload is on.

Comment: did you add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form tag??

Comment: pleas post the complete form HTML

Comment: are you adding the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` code to `add.php`? Because, your form is submitted there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix 'Notice: Undefined index:' in PHP form action?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097897/how-to-fix-notice-undefined-index-in-php-form-action)

Comment: you need to use `$_FILES` to obtain any file requests. However, the way you have it set up. It should work. What problems are you having exactly?

Comment: Yes I added enctype="multipart/form-data" and if(isset($_POST['submit'])) is in add.php file.

Comment: Look at this tutorial http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

Comment: your this code working absolutely fine on my side even with file; post full code or print post and file array after submit

Answer (score 0):

Not every Browser sends the Submit button Value

you should check for your real Input values

```
if(isset($_POST['topic']))
{
    // Form
}
else echo'NOOO';
```

if you want to check if your File is attched

use

```
$_FILE['file1']
```

instead of $_POST

Comment: You should point out the browsers that do not send the "submit" value so that we can test

Comment: My browser is Microsoft Edge. It give same error with Chrome.  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) worked when using only text field but not working after added file field.

Comment: What do you mean by _"...but not working after added file field."_ ?

Comment: Is that same error happening when you use a different browser?

Comment: Firstly I tried only with text field and form submitted to add.php file. But after added file field into form it gave error. Also if I do not choose a file when submitting form, it Works but if I choose a file it give error again.

Comment: Edit your initial question and include all your code because its obviously something else youre not telling or showing us.