# Call to a member function save() on a non-object in yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

HTML Code:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
   <label class="btn btn-default">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
     <input type="checkbox" value="Wiring" name="type_of_service_requires" autocomplete="off">Wiring                        
   </label>

   <label class="btn btn-default electric-ppoints">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
     <input type="checkbox" value="Powerpoints" name="type_of_service_requires" autocomplete="off" checked> Powerpoints
   </label>
```

ASAP
        

     
        Next few days
                                



    
       Residential
    

     
        Commercial

The above line is showing output from HTML code.

Controller code:

```
 public function actionGetQuotes()
 {
    $model = new GetQuotesForm();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request-> post()))
    {

          $model= array_key_exists('type_of_service_requires', $_POST)? $_POST['type_of_service_requires']:"";

          $model= array_key_exists('residential_commercial', $_POST)? $_POST['residential_commercial']:"";

          $model= array_key_exists('work_start_when', $_POST)? $_POST['work_start_when']:"";

          if ($model->save(false))
          {
               Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success', 'New Info Was Saved.');
          }
    }
    return $this->render('get-quotes',['model' => $model,]);
}
```

It's showing:
  PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException

Call to a member function save() on a non-object

Can anyone please help about this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix 'Notice: Undefined index:' in PHP form action?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097897/how-to-fix-notice-undefined-index-in-php-form-action)

Comment: show you html input page .. please. I need to check  what you trying to submit

Comment: what is this, I flag this question as a duplicate and you change the title AND the question? This is a whole new question. By the way $model IS NOT an object. What is the return value of  `$model= array_key....` ? You overwrite your model object in `if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request-> post()))`

Comment: do you have GetQuotesForm model?
if you do, have you included(exp: use app\models\GetQuotesForm) the GetQuotesForm into the file? if you dont have, then create one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is happening here for bellow lines-

```
      $model= array_key_exists('type_of_service_requires', $_POST)? $_POST['type_of_service_requires']:"";

      $model= array_key_exists('residential_commercial', $_POST)? $_POST['residential_commercial']:"";

      $model= array_key_exists('work_start_when', $_POST)? $_POST['work_start_when']:"";
```

Comment all 3 lines and try to submit the form again. It should work without error.

If you want to save submitted values with all above 3 lines then modify them in bellow format-

```
      $model->type_of_service_requires = $_POST['type_of_service_requires'];

      $model->residential_commercial = $_POST['residential_commercial'];

      $model->work_start_when = $_POST['work_start_when'];
```

Now model->save(false) will work after form submission. But if the form submission contains any empty value for any of three attributes then it will display error.

To solve this you can use following way for all three attributes-

```
 if(isset( $_POST['type_of_service_requires'] ))
    $model->type_of_service_requires = $_POST['type_of_service_requires'];

 if(isset( $_POST['residential_commercial'] ))
    $model->residential_commercial = $_POST['residential_commercial'];

 if(isset( $_POST['work_start_when'] ))
    $model->work_start_when = $_POST['work_start_when'];
```

Please add comments if the solution does not work. Add your error details in comments.

Comment: If the code is working as expected then please accept this as answer. It will help others to find this question as solved. Thanks.